# News feed giving error on SharePoint 2016?

Tags: 2016, newsfeed

On SharePoint 2016 farm, on my site News feed giving error:

> SharePoint returned the following error: The remote server returned an
>   error: (401) Unauthorized. Contact your system administrator for help
>   in resolving this problem.

but by farm account it's working fine only issue with user accounts on news feed.

any guess.

Comment: if you are using different services account than it might be issue. check this https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mpriem/2012/08/20/sharepoint-2013-preview-newsfeeds-showing-nothing/

Answer (score 0):

Add the account that is used to run the User Profile Service Application and give it full control.
Add the account that is used to run the Distributed Cache Service and give it full control.And reset the IIS maybe it could help